# Rails activerecord sort_by not sorting? In some situations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I'm so confused.

I have some Notes, and I need them to be sorted by urgency. Urgency is a virtual attribute, determined like so:

```
def urgency
  self.primary_tag.importance * time_since_last_seen
end
```

I don't think this is relevant to the problem.

I have a `get_most_urgent` def, to.. errr... get the most urgent.

```
def self.get_most_urgent
  Note.all.sort_by{|i| - i.urgency}.first
end
```

This works... sometimes. I have this crazy situation in one of my tests (sorry I call my test Notes @bob and @trey. I should really change them)

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> @trey.urgency
 => 12
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> @bob.urgency
=> 9
 [3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> Note.get_most_urgent
 => #<Note:0x007fdf801924d8 id: 732, body: "bob", todo_by: nil, 
 last_seen: Mon, 19 Feb 2018, created_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:00:06 
  UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:00:06 UTC +00:00, 
 seentoday: false>
```

As you can see, it returns bob as the most urgent. I thought I just must not understand how sort works, and change the `- i.urgency` to just `i.urgency`... but this causes another test to fail in a similar way....

Any idea what is going on?! What don't I understand about sort_by?

-----EDIT--------

This was nothing to do with sort, it was a persistence problem... you can't set attributes like this `self.last_seen = Date.today`. You need to save it! Or use a pattern like: `self.update(last_seen: Date.today)`

Comment: Is trey not persisted, perhaps? So it's not seen by `Note.all`.

Comment: good idea, but nope:
`[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> Note.all
=> [#<Note:0x007fb8158cbe80
  id: 774,
  body: "bob",
  todo_by: nil,
  last_seen: Mon, 19 Feb 2018,
  created_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00,
  seentoday: false>,
 #<Note:0x007fb8158cb110
  id: 775,
  body: "Trey",
  todo_by: nil,
  last_seen: Mon, 19 Feb 2018,
  created_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00,
  seentoday: false>]`

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, what about `Note.all.max_by(&:urgency)`?

Comment: Another crazy idea: does `time_since_last_seen` change after you read it (directly or via `urgency`)?

Comment: Hi, don't know whether I should start a new question or what, but here is the situation. Inspired by Sergio's question above, I did some debugging, and when you are 'in' the model (i.e I put pry in the urgency method) for both the  Notes, importance is 5 (the default) and last_seen is today (also the default) (so of course, whichever is the most urgent is arbitrary). I will continue to investigate, but for some reason values are not being saved. Thanks everyone for their help so far.

Comment: yeah, start a new, more focused question.

Comment: `Note.all.sort_by` loads _all_ notes from your database into memory and sorts them in memory - just to return one single note. This is a pattern that doesn't scale well when you have a high number of notes in your database. It would be much faster to order and pick the first note directly in the database. Can you please show how `primary_tag.importance` and `time_since_last_seen` are defined? There still might be an option to order the records in the database.

Comment: @spickermann so primary_tag.importance is just a model with an importance attribute - set by the user - and `time_since_last_seen` is this: 
`def time_since_last_seen
    ((Date.today - self.last_seen) + 1).to_i
 end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading all notes into memory first just sort them and return the first record doesn't scale well with a higher number of notes in the database.

Instead I would suggest to sort the record in the database and only load the one record you actually need.

I would add a `by_urgency` scope to the `Note` model that allows to sort the record in the database:

```
# in models/note.rb
scope :by_urgency, lambda {
  joins(:primary_tag).
    order("tags.importance * DATEDIFF(day, notes.created_at, NOW()) DESC")
}
```

With this scope you can rewrite your `get_most_urgent` method like this:

```
def self.get_most_urgent
  Note.by_urgency.first
end
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it's useful & true... although the actual issue was unrelated to the sort function as detailed in the edit above...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing why it shouldn't work, but it might be the way it's parsing the unary operator?

Maybe try...

```
Notel.all.sort_by{|note| (0 - note.urgency) }.first
```

Or you could try this instead...

```
Note.all.sort {|a,b| b.urgency <=> a.urgency}.first
```

Comment: These still fail in the same way. Something very odd is going on. From pry:
    `[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> @trey.urgency
=> 12`
`[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> @bob.urgency
=> 9`
`[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Note>)> Note.all.sort {|a,b| b.urgency <=> a.urgency}.first
=> #<Note:0x007fb8159dbe88 id: 774, body: "bob", todo_by: nil, last_seen: Mon, 19 Feb 2018, created_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:28:58 UTC +00:00, seentoday: false>`

how is this possible?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `primary_tag.importance` is an integer?  Both the multiply and the minus wouldn't generate an error for strings.

Try this...

```
def urgency
  self.primary_tag.importance.to_i * time_since_last_seen.to_i
end
```

Comment: If it was a string, `urgency` wouldn't produce an integer, though. Which it does.

Comment: yes, sadly this didn't work... Sergio, I'm investigating your above comment.. think you are on to something